# Facebook Connect Email hash function for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, hash, facebook

Does anyone have a working class or function to create the hashed email that is sent to facebook to register email addresses with connect.registerUsers?

Comment: is this please sendz the codez, albeit disguised? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out on my own

Imports System.Net

Imports tb2CoreLib

Imports Microsoft.Xml.Schema.Linq

Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Imports facebook.Utility

Imports Microsoft.Xml

Imports System.Xml

Imports System.Web

Public Class FacebookConnect

Public Function EmailHash(ByVal email As String) As String

```
    email = email.ToLower().Trim()
    Dim rawBytes As Byte() = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(email)

    Dim crc As New Crc32()
    Dim crcResult As Byte() = crc.ComputeHash(rawBytes)
    Dim hexstring As String = Me.ToHexString(crcResult)

    Dim crcLResult As Long = Me.HexToDec(hexstring)

    Dim md5 As MD5 = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim md5Result As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(rawBytes)
    Dim md5Data As String = Me.ToHexString(md5Result).ToLower()

    Return (crcLResult.ToString() & "_") + md5Data
End Function
```

end class

Imports System

Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Crc32

```
Inherits HashAlgorithm

Public Const DefaultPolynomial As UInt32 = &HEDB88320UI

Public Const DefaultSeed As UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFFUI

Private Shadows hash As UInt32
Private seed As UInt32
Private table As UInt32()
Private Shared defaultTable As UInt32()

Public Sub New()
    table = InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial)
    seed = DefaultSeed
    Initialize()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal polynomial As UInt32, ByVal seed As UInt32)
    table = InitializeTable(polynomial)
    Me.seed = seed
    Initialize()
End Sub

Public Overloads Overrides Sub Initialize()
    hash = seed
End Sub

Protected Overloads Overrides Sub HashCore(ByVal buffer As Byte(), ByVal start As Integer, ByVal length As Integer)
    hash = CalculateHash(table, hash, buffer, start, length)
End Sub

Protected Overloads Overrides Function HashFinal() As Byte()
    Dim hashBuffer As Byte() = UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(Not hash)
    Me.HashValue = hashBuffer
    Return hashBuffer
End Function

Public Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property HashSize() As Integer
    Get
        Return 32
    End Get
End Property

Public Shared Function Compute(ByVal buffer As Byte()) As UInt32
    Return Not CalculateHash(InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial), DefaultSeed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Function

Public Shared Function Compute(ByVal seed As UInt32, ByVal buffer As Byte()) As UInt32
    Return Not CalculateHash(InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial), seed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Function

Public Shared Function Compute(ByVal polynomial As UInt32, ByVal seed As UInt32, ByVal buffer As Byte()) As UInt32
    Return Not CalculateHash(InitializeTable(polynomial), seed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Function

Private Shared Function InitializeTable(ByVal polynomial As UInt32) As UInt32()
    If polynomial = DefaultPolynomial AndAlso defaultTable IsNot Nothing Then
        Return defaultTable
    End If

    Dim createTable As UInt32() = New UInt32(255) {}
    For i As UInt32 = 0 To 255
        Dim entry As UInt32 = DirectCast(i, UInt32)
        For j As Integer = 0 To 7
            If (entry And 1) = 1 Then
                entry = (entry >> 1) Xor polynomial
            Else
                entry = entry >> 1
            End If
        Next
        createTable(i) = entry
    Next

    If polynomial = DefaultPolynomial Then
        defaultTable = createTable
    End If

    Return createTable
End Function

Private Shared Function CalculateHash(ByVal table As UInt32(), ByVal seed As UInt32, ByVal buffer As Byte(), ByVal start As Integer, ByVal size As Integer) As UInt32
    Dim crc As UInt32 = seed
    For i As Integer = start To size - 1
        crc = (crc >> 8) Xor table(buffer(i) Xor crc And &HFF)

    Next
    Return crc
End Function

Private Function UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(ByVal x As UInt32) As Byte()
    Return New Byte() {CByte(((x >> 24) And &HFF)), CByte(((x >> 16) And &HFF)), CByte(((x >> 8) And &HFF)), CByte((x And &HFF))}
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

`Connect.registerUsers` uses, [I believe](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect.registerUsers) merely the [normal MD5 hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28VS.80%29.aspx) as implemented in the .NET runtime.

The MD5 documentation page even includes an example code:

```
Function getMd5Hash(ByVal input As String) As String
    ' Create a new instance of the MD5 object. '
    Dim md5Hasher As MD5 = MD5.Create()

    ' Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash. '
    Dim data As Byte() = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input))

    ' Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes '
    ' and create a string. '
    Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

    ' Loop through each byte of the hashed data '
    ' and format each one as a hexadecimal string. '
    For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1
        sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next

    ' Return the hexadecimal string. '
    Return sBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

<del>However, there’s a [.NET client library](http://facebook.codeplex.com/) for Facebook anyway, why not use it?</del>

*Duh.* The .NET library doesn’t have support for `Connect` (yet)